# OneLogin - Get logged in user's ID

Tags: api, get, onelogin

I need to get logged in user's ID on a web page where user is authenticated via OneLogin. We need to use OneLogin's REST API endpoint that can give me logged in user's details.

https://api.domainname.onelogin.com/api/1/users/:id

For above REST API I need user's ID.

Can you please help me figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying the user has a OneLogin session?  Or that you are using the API to authenticate the user using the delegated authentication API?

If you are using this: https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/users/create-session-login-token

The user ID is in the response.

Comment: Hi David, I have a OneLogin session already. I need to user id for logged in user from this session. Once I get user id, I need to call Get Use By ID API and get more user profile properties.

Answer (score 0):

If the application you're writing supports SAML then part of the SAML assertion you got from OneLogin should be a unique user attribute (email or username)

Your best bet is then to get that user from OneLogin by using that attribute -

https://api.<us_or_eu>.onelogin.com/api/1/users?email=user@test.com
or
https://api.<us_or_eu>.onelogin.com/api/1/users?username=testuser

And since that value is unique, it will only return the one matching record (i.e. The current user)